# Call of Duty Warzone PC - Regular Screen Freeze and Full PC Crash

Tags: technical-issues, call-of-duty-warzone

I have returned to Call of Duty Warzone recently and have been experiencing some freezes mid-game. They happen regularly, but also in very inconsistent ways. It can happen every couple of minutes, and the only way to unfreeze it without crashing the game is to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> out of the game and come back, which gets me killed 9 times out of 10. I also get the occasional complete PC freeze (where I have to manually restart the PC) or a blue screen.

When the freeze happens, the screen (only of Warzone freezes, not my other monitors or apps) and the sounds go haywire (like a music super short / loop effect) until I <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> out and back in.

I have checked out every guide out there to try and fix this issue, from scanning and repairing the game to optimising my graphics settings, updating drivers, making sure the game uses all the CPU cores, changing the render API to DirectX11 with the command line option `-D3D11`, disabling V-Sync, Disabling Windows Gaming Mode, etc., but nothing seems to do the trick.

I have monitored my PC's performance during gameplay and none of the components—CPU, GPU, Disk or Network—is maxed out, so I am very puzzled at what is happening. Some say it might be GPU overclocking (my GPU is on factory settings, but it's an MSI 2070 OC, which is factory overclocked), so I guess that might be an issue, although that would surprise me.

This makes the game very frustrating to play, borderline unplayable, because sometimes crashes can happen multiple times in a row. It is the only game in which this happens so I was wondering if anybody else is experiencing this issue, or if anybody has found a fix for it. I did notice it happens much more regularly in multiplayer (Modern Warfare) than in Warzone itself, but it also does happen in the latter.

I used to play the game a lot and it would never do that kind of thing. Is this because of a new patch, or is the game just poorly optimised for my hardware?

**Here is my hardware information:**

```
MOBO:           Gigabyte X399 AORUS XTREME
CPU:            AMD Threadripper 2950x
RAM:            32Gb RIPJAW 4 DDR4
DISK:           Samsung SSD 970 PRO 1 TB
                   3x Iron Wolf 4 TB 5600 RPM
GPU:            MSI GeForce RTX 2070 OC
PSU:            EVGA 850 G3
MONITOR:        Predator XB271HU 27" G-Sync

OS:             Windows 10
Nvidia Drivers: 516.94
```

**The game is installed on the Iron Wolf HDD because it is massive**

I am an IT and software engineer, so I am comfortable with more technical solutions and talk, so don't be afraid to give intricate details if you have them.

**Update:** Im using Nvidia Geforce experience optimised settings at the moment and it seems to moslty resolve the issue, it will have the occasional stutter which is not ideal but definitly makes the game less frustrating to play.